# Send 'nil' for unchecked checkboxes - UJS, Rails 4

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, checkbox

I am trying to `update_attributes` for orders using `check_box` form tags inside an HTML table:

```
...
<td>
  <%= form_for order, url: toggle_shipped_state_path(order.id), remote: true do |f| %>
    <% if order.shipped_or_delivered.nil? %> #<= items that weren't shipped
      <%= f.check_box :shipped_or_delivered, class: 'toggle-shipped' %>
    <% else %>
      <%= f.check_box :shipped_or_delivered, class: 'toggle-shipped', checked: true %>
    <% end %>
    <%= f.submit 'Shipped' %>
  <% end  %>
</td>
...
```

At the end of my view, I'm loading `my-sales.js`, which has:

```
jQuery.fn.submitOnCheck = function() {

  this.find('input[type=submit]').remove();
  this.find('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    $(this).parent('form').submit();
    $(this).closest('tr').toggleClass('success');
  });
  return this;
}

$('table').find('input[checked]').each(function(){
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $(this).closest('tr').addClass('success');
    }
  });

$('form.edit_order').submitOnCheck();
```

My `toggle_shipped_state` action is:

```
def toggle_shipped_state
  @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
  @order.update_attributes(shipped_or_delivered: Time.now)
end
```

Checking the box works fine and `@order`'s `shipped_and_delivered` attribute gets updated correctly. However, unchecking the check box does nothing. How can I make sure that unchecking the checkbox creates an AJAX call to update the corresponding order's `shipped_and_delivered` attribute with `nil` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As always, I overlooked the most obvious problem with my design. The controller action was a one-trick pony, which would only update the `shipped_or_delivered` attribute with `Time.now`. Since the value of a checkbox is either `1` for `true` or `0` for `false`, controller action needs to accommodate both scenarios. So instead of:

```
def toggle_shipped_state
  @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
  @order.update_attributes(shipped_or_delivered: Time.now)
end
```

I should have done:

```
def toggle_shipped_state
  @order = Order.find(params[:order_id])
  if params[:order][:shipped_or_delivered] == '0'
    @order.update_attributes(shipped_or_delivered: nil)
  else
    @order.update_attributes(shipped_or_delivered: Time.now)
  end
end
```